# PHP: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, sql

I have a class named player that creates, deletes and controls if a player entity exists. In another file, I have the database connection with `PDO` and, finally, in third file I have the call to player class. Here's all the code:

file: **player.php**

```
<?php
    class player
    {
        private $pdo;
        private $network_id;
        public $color;

        public function __construct($pdo, $network_id, $color)
        {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
            $this->network_id = $network_id;
            $this->color = $color;
        }

        public function create_player()
        {
            if(!$this->exists_player())
            {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO players SET network_id = :network_id';
                $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array(':network_id' => $this->network_id));
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'error';
            }
        }

        public function delete_player()
        {
            if($this->exists_player())
            {
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM players WHERE network_id = :network_id';
                $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array(':network_id' => $this->network_id));
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        private function exists_player()
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players WHERE network_id = '.$this->network_id;
            $result = $this->pdo->exec($sql);

            if($result > 0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

file: **test.php**

```
<?php
   include './Php/db_connection.php';
   include './Php/player.php';

    $player = new player($pdo, 1112, 'red');

    $player->create_player();
?>
```

file: **db_connection.php**

```
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=myDbName', 'dbUtent', 'myPassword');
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

The thing is that when I call **test.php**, I get this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in F:\Software\Coding_Development_Software\Server\wamp\www\myProject\Ajax\Cube\Php\player.php on line 21`

*All code is an exemple.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that you need to fetch until it fails for a row fetch attempt. In fact, your own exception is telling you the solution:

`Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. in F:\Software\Coding_Development_Software\Server\wamp\www\myProject\Ajax\Cube\Php\player.php on line 21`

Comment: In `exists_player` you should use `->query` rather than `->exec` to get the result of your `SELECT`, then you will have a `PDOStatement` that you can do the Fetch on that is described here.  If this returns an array with values then you can check the COUNT value (or just SELECT * and count the resulting array).